# How to store a Form element File into local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input-type-file

I am developing a react application where it reads the excel data into JSON object. I have a form element input type file which on change loads the JSON data form an xlsx file . Now I want to save file details (not file data) into local storage so that I can use these details to read the file later.

#### REACT CODE

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from "axios";

function App() {



let handleOnClick=function(event){
  console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  let data=new FormData();
  data.append("selectedFile",event.target.files[0]);
  axios
        .post("http://localhost:4001/upload",data)
        .then(res=>{
          console.log(res["data"]);
    });



    localStorage.setItem("selectedFile",event.target.files[0]);
    let selectedFile=localStorage.getItem("selectedFile");
    let data2=new FormData();
    data2.append("selectedFile",selectedFile);

    axios.post("http://localhost:4001/upload",data2)
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    })
}


  return (
    <form>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleOnClick}/>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The above code is working fine and could load the data for Form variable Data but not for Data2

Could any one please help how to proceed with this

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` allows you to store **strings**, and only strings. You can't store a reference to a file on the user's disk.

`event.target.files[0]` is not a string, so you'll store whatever you get from implicitly calling `toString()` on it.

The only information you could store from a picked file that would let you later read it back and send it in an Ajax request is **the content of the file** which you'd need to read with `FileReader` and convert to a string (so you might been to base64 encode it if it isn't a text file in the first place). Note that you are likely to hit storage limits.

Answer (score -2):

In javascript, we can set value in local storage in key-value pair

**for set:-**

```
localStorage.lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
```

**for retrieve:-**

```
document.getElementById("lname").innerHTML=localStorage.lname
```

Comment: While you can store any kind of data on any object, the point of localStorage is to preserve the data between page loads and you have to use its `setItem` method to do that.

Comment: This line is used for set the item and the key is lname localStorage.lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;

Comment: You already posted that code in your attempt at providing an answer. I just explained why it was unsuitable.

Comment: `document.getElementById("lname").value` doesn't even hold the data that the OP wants to store.

Comment: yes obviously for set the value we have to call the set method